# put an id reference in a div tag

Tags: html, w3c-validation

i have to insert an id reference in a div. i've create an rif attribute:

```
 <div rif="5" id="25km" class="mini_button_form">25km</div>
```

but this is w3c invalid.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

"ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")." (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your [doctype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration). For HTML5, I'd recommend changing it to:

```
<div data-rif="5" id="km25" class="mini_button_form">25km</div>
```

If it has to be (X)HTML4 then you could put the data in the `class` attribute and use something like the jQuery [Metadata plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata).

```
<div id="km25" class="mini_button_form { rif:5 }">25km</div>
```

(Note I changed the ID's too, as Konrad suggested)